# Postman pre-request script unable to find reference for jQuery

Tags: jquery, postman

I am trying to run the following code on Postman pre-execute script.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'some-url',
    type: 'post',
    data: {},
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + authHeader,
        timestamp: timestamp,
        signature: signed_signature
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

I am getting the following error.

`There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

How can I load jquery into the pre-request script?

Comment: Did you add jquery library??

Comment: add jquery library on the top before any other scripts.

Comment: @NagaSaiA@Animay the same exact code runs on my co-worker's machine without any jquery imports. So I am guessing that postman's pre-execute script loads jQuery by default. or can this be achieved by a setting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found that there are two types of Postman apps. 
earlier I am using native Mac Postman application.
I switched to Postman-chrome web app and I am able to use jQuery inside the pre-request script without any import/require statement.

### Update

Postman is deprecating Chrome app and instead encouraging users to go with native apps for mac/windows/Linux.

Use Postman's built-in `pm.sendRequest` method to send requests asynchronously.

Here is an example taken from the [postman blog post](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/10/03/send-asynchronous-requests-with-postmans-pm-api/).

```
pm.sendRequest('https://postman-echo.com/get', function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        pm.environment.set("variable_key", "new_value");
    }
});
```

So we can replace the jQuery ajax requests with `pm.sendRequest` and make it work.

Comment: I found this did not work consistently if you are depending on data from the $.ajax callback for the main Postman request. It seems the pre-request script is not guaranteed to be executed before the main request. 


This looks like an older issue with underlying Chrome, but I still found the same behavior as of a month ago: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/644


Are you relying on the callback to populate data for the main request? If so, is it working consistently for you? And have you used any other environment or just a Mac/Chrome?

Comment: @MichaelFinger i haven’t faced the issue you mentioned. i only tried it on mac.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question for the other 90 million people who want to actually use jquery in their scripts

Comment: @JoePhillips I know it is not solving the problem of importing jQuery into Postman. But If postman is giving another option to make asynchronous call then it should be fine.